# How many torus can I find as a subgraph of a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-graph-theory

I am wondering whether there is a way to count how many non-isomorphic torus triangulation given its vertex number.

I currently have no clue about how to solve this problem. Can anyone give some hints or ideas?